# Trigger click event manually in Dojo CheckBox

Tags: javascript, events, dom, dojo

In my application, I have this code:

```
postCreate: function(){

  // ...

  // Change the listWidget's order depending on whether the checkbox is
  // ticked or not
  self.extraWidget.orderByNameWidget.on( 'click', function( e ){
    var orderByNameWidget = this;
    field = orderByNameWidget.get('value') ? 'firstName' : 'lastName';

    // Make up the collection with the initial filters
    var collection = self.store;
    if( self.initialFilter ) collection = collection.filter( self.initialFilter );
    collection = collection.sort( field );

    self.listWidget.set('collection', collection);

  });
```

This code is there so that the user can click on a checkbox (orderByNameWidget), and change the sorting of contacts.
orderByNameWidget is a normal Dojo CheckBox.

Now, I have a global setting of what that value should be to start with. The neater way to deal with it would be setting the value of the checkbox, and then trigger the event:

```
  // Artificially emit the initial click if the default says so    
  if( ConfigVars.workspacesUsersInfo.orderByNameDefault ){
    self.extraWidget.orderByNameWidget.set( 'value', true );

    self.extraWidget.orderByNameWidget.emit( 'click', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true });
  }
```

While the first line works (setting the widget), the second one doesn't -- the 'click' event is never actually triggered for the widget.

I tried every single possible combination, emitting this event on the domNode etc. -- but no, it doesn't seem to want to do anything.
In Button.html, the basis for CheckBox, Dojo has:

```
 data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:__onClick"
```

I wonder if that's the problem. So... what should I write for a *full* simulation of the checkbox click? Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you can't use the `change` event instead of `click` to begin with?  That ought to fire on both user clicks and programmatic changes.  (And keyboard events, for that matter, which `click` likely won't fire on.)

Comment: You mean, emitting a change event rather than click?

Comment: I mean, Ken, can you see that my purpose is to *trigger* the event manually, rather than attach myself to the event?

Comment: I mean, the `change` event already fires when you set the value programmatically, which seems like what you're trying to do anyway.  I guess I don't understand why you're fixated on listening to and emitting another event when `change` seems like exactly what you want.

Comment: You are completely right Ken! Now, question stays: why didn't emitting the click event programmatically work? I have never actually managed to emit an event manually, and get the event's callback to fire. Why is that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `_WidgetBase#emit` always emits a DOM event, whereas depending on the widget, `widget.on('click', ...)` may in fact be aspecting a method, not listening for a DOM event.  Dijit's back-compat code for `on` isn't exactly straightforward.

Comment: I really hope delite will be totally straightforward and will do away with all the back compatibility issues that make dojo so complex...